# css transform open div to right like a "book" cover

Tags: css, css-transitions

Hi for a webshop i want the product block to open like a book. and show a image on de inside-left (when opened)

i tried to do this. It works ok but i want the black div to open to the left. this one will contain the image. When i put a negivate -180 degrees it does not seem to work ok.

```css
                    .left,
                    .right {
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 200px;
                      float: left;
                      color: white;
                      position: absolute;
                    }
                    .left {
                      background: red;
                      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
                      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
                      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
                      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px;
                      border-top-left-radius: 100px;
                      border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
                      height: 250px;
                      padding: 0;
                      border: 10px solid #10832d;
                    }
                    .right {
                      background: black;
                      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
                      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
                      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
                      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px;
                      border-top-left-radius: 100px;
                      border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
                      height: 250px;
                      padding: 0;
                      border: 10px solid #10832d;
                    }
                    .wrapper {
                      perspective: 1000px;
                      perspective-origin: 100%;
                      100%;
                      ;
                      -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
                      -webkit-perspective-origin: 100%;
                      100%;
                      ;
                    }
                    .wrapper:hover .right {
                      transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
                      transform: rotateY(180deg);
                      transform-origin: 100%;
                      0;
                      transition: transform 1s;
                      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                      -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
                      0;
                      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
                    }
```

```html
<div style="width:50%">
  <div class="col-md-3 wrapper" style="position:relative;min-height:250px;">

    <div class="left">sdfsdf</div>
    <div class="right">sdfdsfds</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `transform-origin` not with `rotation degree`, *in your case*:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 100%; 0;
//                        ^ X   ^ Y
```

That means `x-axis` offset `100%` of div *(full offset on x-axis)*

No problem, Now just reset the origin to zero *( to start rotation from begin of div )* like this :

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0;
```

Also don't forget `float: right` because the div will open to the left.

***CSS / HTML :***

```css
.left,.right {
width:100%;
height:200px;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
}

.left {
background:red;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:100px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:100px;
border-top-left-radius:100px;
border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
height:250px;
border:10px solid #10832d;
padding:0;
}

.right {
background:#000;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:100px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:100px;
border-top-left-radius:100px;
border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
height:250px;
border:10px solid #10832d;
padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
perspective:1000px;
perspective-origin:100%;
-webkit-perspective:1000px;
-webkit-perspective-origin:100%;
}

.wrapper:hover .right {
transform:rotateY(180deg);
transform-origin:0;
transition:transform 1s;
-webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
-webkit-transform-origin:0;
-webkit-transition:0 1s;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%; float:right">
  <div class="col-md-3 wrapper" style="position:relative;min-height:250px;">

    <div class="left">left side</div>
    <div class="right">right side</div>

  </div>
</div>
```